# Spring Cloud Gateway: Monitor health and location for Sample code

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, api-gateway

I'm fairly new to spring cloud gateway and I am thinking of using it as a main gateway to my application.

I was wondering if Spring cloud gateway provides the capability to monitor health of the gateway (and also monitor the health of the microservices that have the /health endpoint)?

Also i'm wondering if Spring cloud gateway supports API versioning too?

What would be really good is if anyone can point me to the direction where there is sample code that is available for me to try these things out?

Thanks

Comment: That's three questions, not sure of SO procedure there. What would you consider the health of a gateway? It is a spring boot app, so all of its actuator endpoints are there. There's nothing specific for versioning, but simple filters would work. https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-gateway-sample

Comment: good thanks @spencergibb . Will avoid asking mulitple questions on SO. But yes, useful information. thanks